# Nested Marshmallow fields and Sqlalchemy relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

In my sqlalchemy classes I have the following classes:

```
class FooBar(Model):
    __tablename__ = ‘foobar’
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)

    foonr = Column('foonr', Integer, ForeignKey('foo.nr'), nullable=False)
    barnr = Column('barnr', String, ForeignKey('bar.nr'), nullable=False)

class Foo(Model):
    __tablename__ = ‘foo’
    nr = Column('nr', Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_name = Column(‘name’,String)


class Bar(Model):
   __tablename__ = ‘bar’
   nr = Column('nr', Integer, primary_key=True)
   bar_name = Column(‘name’,String)
   foo_bar = relationship('foobar', uselist=False)
```

When I try to nest the classes Foo or Bar in a Marshmallow Schema for FooBar I’m not getting any results (the dictionaries don't have any references to the classes Foo or Bar).

```
class FooBarSchema(Schema):
   id = fields.Int()
   foo = fields.Nested('FooSchema', many=False)
   bar = fields.Nested('BarSchema', many=False)
```

How can I get the Foo and Bar classes in the results of the FooBarSchema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I'll give you the solution to your problem.

```
class FooBar(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foobar'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    foonr = Column('foonr', Integer, ForeignKey('foo.nr'), nullable=False)
    barnr = Column('barnr', String, ForeignKey('bar.nr'), nullable=False)
    foo = relationship("Foo", uselist=False)
    bar = relationship("Bar", uselist=False)

class FooBarSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()   
    foo = fields.Nested('FooSchema', many=False)
    bar = fields.Nested('BarSchema', many=False)
```

But analyzing your code I think we can make it more pythonic.

**If, and only if, you do not have extra data in the association table**, we can change some things.

Looking at SQLAlchemy doc's for an [Many To Many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) relationship, we can to use the `secondary` parameter of the `relationship()`. 
We have to keep class as you currently have and the class `Bar` like that:

```
class Bar(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    nr = Column('nr', Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_name = Column('name',String)
    foos = relationship("Foo", secondary="foobar", backref="bars")
```

So in `Bar.foos` we have a list of `Foo` objects, and the `backref` also makes it possible to have an `Bar` list in `Foo.bars`.

Now we have to configure the `BarSchema` and `FooSchema` classes.

```
class FooSchema(Schema):
    nr = fields.Int()   
    foo_name = fields.Str()
    bars = fields.Nested('BarSchema', exclude=('foos',), many=True)

class BarSchema(Schema):
    nr = fields.Int()   
    bar_name = fields.Str()
    foos = fields.Nested('FooSchema', exclude=('bars',), many=True)
```

The `exclude` is to avoid recursive problems.

Comment: OK what about if we *do* have extra data in the association table?

Comment: Then you will work with [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) that will behave like Many-to-One and One-to-Many, 
where the Association Object will be the "One". 
As Association Object will also be a model it may have its own Schema class. If you have questions or difficulties, create a question and I will try to help you with a code sample

Comment: Remembering that there are other strategies when using Association Object, such as using [Association Proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html), then the configurations of your Schema classes will depend on the strategy adopted